# Trouble getting TicTacToe game to run java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

My assignment was to create a tic tac toe game that allowed the X to play against the computer. She wanted the player and computer moves to be void, the check winner to be int, the print and init board to also be int as well. I don't think I met all of them, but I just want it to run and actually output right. This is my first year in comp sci also. For the most part, I think my logic works, it's just for the computer move method, I was confused as to how to get random moves in a 3x3 array so that may very well make no sense. My issue is in the main method, trying to use the do..while loop to allow the computer to display it's move. My machineTurn method is supposed to be a void method, but the error says it has to be an int. I'm not sure what is wrong now but, I've been looking at this code for a while. I've commented a good bit of it. my error is:

java:58: error: incompatible types

move = machineTurn(theSeed);

required: int

found: void

1 error

Process completed.

```
import java.util.*;
public class TTT
{
public static final int EMPTY = 0;
public static final int COMPUTER = 2;
public static final int NONE = 0;
public static final int USER = 1;
public static final int theSeed = 0;


// Name-constants to represent the various states of the game
public static final int PLAYING = 0;
public static final int DRAW = 1;
public static final int USER_WON = 2;
public static final int COMPUTER_WON = 3;

// The game board and the game status
public static final int ROWS = 3, COLS = 3; // number of rows and columns
public static int[][] board = new int[ROWS][COLS]; // game board in 2D array
                                                  //  containing (EMPTY, CROSS, NOUGHT)
public static int currentState;  // the current state of the game
                                 // (PLAYING, DRAW, CROSS_WON, NOUGHT_WON)
public static int currentPlayer; // the current player (CROSS or NOUGHT)
public static int currentRow, currentCol; // current seed's row and column

public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // the input Scanner

public static void main(String[] args)
{
int move;
int winner;

initBoard();
printBoard();
// play the game once
do{
    yourTurn(currentPlayer);
    machineTurn(theSeed);
    updateGame(currentPlayer, currentRow, currentCol);
    printBoard();
    //print message if game-over
    if (currentState == USER_WON)
    {
        System.out.println(" You won! You beat the computer! Congratulations!");
    }
    else if ( currentState == COMPUTER_WON)
    {
        System.out.println(" You lost! The Computer Beat you! Sorry! ");
    }
    else if ( currentState == DRAW)
    {
        System.out.println(" No One won! It's a draw! ");
    }
    //switch player
    currentPlayer = (currentPlayer == USER) ? COMPUTER : USER;
    if( currentPlayer == COMPUTER)
    {
        move = machineTurn(theSeed);
        System.out.println("Computer move: " + move);
    }           
   }while( currentState == PLAYING); //repeat if not game over
 }

//initialize game board contents    
public static void initBoard()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row)
    {
     for (int col = 0; col < COLS; ++col) 
     {
        board[row][col] = EMPTY;  // all cells empty
     }
    }

}
public static void printBoard()
{
 for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row) 
 {
   for (int col = 0; col < COLS; ++col) 
   {
    printCell(board[row][col]); // print each of the cells
     if (col != COLS - 1) 
     {
       System.out.print("|");   // print vertical partition
     }
   }
     System.out.println();
     if (row != ROWS - 1)
      {
        System.out.println("-----------"); // print horizontal partition
      }
  }
  System.out.println();
}
public static void printCell(int content) {
  switch (content) {
     case EMPTY:  System.out.print("   "); break;
     case COMPUTER: System.out.print(" O "); break;
     case USER:  System.out.print(" X "); break;
  }
}
public static boolean checkWinner(int theSeed, int currentRow,int currentCol)
{
  return (board[currentRow][0] == theSeed         // 3-in-the-row
               && board[currentRow][1] == theSeed
               && board[currentRow][2] == theSeed
          || board[0][currentCol] == theSeed      // 3-in-the-column
               && board[1][currentCol] == theSeed
               && board[2][currentCol] == theSeed
          || currentRow == currentCol            // 3-in-the-diagonal
               && board[0][0] == theSeed
               && board[1][1] == theSeed
               && board[2][2] == theSeed
          || currentRow + currentCol == 2  // 3-in-the-opposite-diagonal
               && board[0][2] == theSeed
               && board[1][1] == theSeed
               && board[2][0] == theSeed);
}
 public static boolean isDraw()
 {
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
        {
            if (board[row][col] == EMPTY)
            {
                return false; //an empty cell found, not draw, exit
            }
        }
    }
    return true; //no empty cell, it's draw
}
/* Player with the "theSeed" makes one move, with input validation.
   Update global variables "currentRow" and "currentCol". */
public static void yourTurn(int theSeed)
{
    boolean validInput = false;
    do {
     if (theSeed == USER)
      {
        System.out.print("Player 'X', enter your move (row[1-3] column[1-3]): ");
      }
     int row = in.nextInt() - 1;  // array index starts at 0 instead of 1
     int col = in.nextInt() - 1;
     if (row >= 0 && row < ROWS && col >= 0 && col < COLS && board[row][col] == EMPTY) {
        currentRow = row;
        currentCol = col;
        board[currentRow][currentCol] = theSeed;  // update game-board content
        validInput = true;  // input okay, exit loop
     } else {
        System.out.println("This move at (" + (row + 1) + "," + (col + 1)
              + ") is not valid. Try again...");
     }
  } while (!validInput);  // repeat until input is valid
}
/* supposed to be machine's random move after USER has gone */ 
public static void machineTurn(int theSeed)
{
    int move = (int)(Math.random()*9);
boolean validInput = false;
do{
    if(theSeed == COMPUTER);
    {
        board[(int)(move/3)][move%3] = currentPlayer;
    }


int row = in.nextInt() - 1;  // array index starts at 0 instead of 1
     int col = in.nextInt() - 1;
     if (row >= 0 && row < ROWS && col >= 0 && col < COLS && board[row][col] == EMPTY) {
        currentRow = row;
        currentCol = col;
        board[currentRow][currentCol] = theSeed;  // update game-board content
        }
       }while(validInput = true); // input okay, exit loop

}
public static void updateGame(int theSeed, int currentRow, int currentCol)
{
    if(checkWinner(theSeed, currentRow,currentCol))
    {
        currentState = (theSeed == USER) ? USER_WON : COMPUTER_WON;
    }
    else if (isDraw()) //check for draw
    {
        currentState = DRAW;
    }
 }
  //otherwise, no change to currentState (Still PLAYING)
}
```

Also, for extra credit, we have to create a method that doesn't allow the player to win. It can be a draw, but the computer always wins. Can anyone give me a hint on how to go about starting to code that? I'll name that machineSmartMode.

Comment: Writing the code that doesn't allow the player to win (only draw/lose) isn't a question of being a good programmer as much as it is a question of understanding the game you're programming.  Study up on tic-tac-toe.

Comment: You can use this algorithm: http://xkcd.com/832/

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what and where the problem is.

Comment: Your error on line 58 is due to your trying to assign the int move with a method that returns not an int, but a void. You may just say `machineMove(theSeed)` and drop the `move=`.

Comment: `move =` means that the compiler expects the rest of the line to end calculating a value. But it just calls a method that does not return a value (a `void` method). So...

Comment: @rajah9, if I take the move= out,  it  says that move wasn't initialized. I need it to display where the computer is moving. My code was working fine until I tried to change the machine move, now I'm semi lost on how to get it to work

Comment: @nhgrif I feel like I understand that, but then it's not connecting... I'm just not sure how to start that method... but I'll try some things

Comment: @Kevin I understand where and what this issue is, I might not have worded that right in my question, I just don't know how to fix it and still meet my teacher requirements of having the computers move be a void method. The way I had it before was an int, but I don't want points taken off.

Answer (score 0):

Your static method `machineTurn` is `void`, but you're trying to assign the result to an `int`. There isn't a result.

Comment: How should I change it so that the machine move is void, like yourTurn and it still displays the move?

Comment: You have several other issues in your code, so this isn't really going to help much... but change the method signature to `int` and return the machine's move from the method.

Comment: mind telling me what my other issues are? I fixed all of that and now it only prints the empty board... I don't know what I did wrong... I thought I knew what I was doing...

Comment: Well, for one thing `if(theSeed == COMPUTER);` there shouldn't be a semicolon at the end of that if.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I didn't even realize that... Is there any other obvious mistakes?

Comment: Why are you looping with `validInput` in `machineTurn()`? It's never set to `true`.

Comment: I didn't know how to get the machine turn to print using a 2D array and still make random moves, so I just copied from the method above it. The machine method is the one method that I have no clue whether it's right or not... I wasn't sure how to code it. Should I just take that line out? or...

Comment: that's supposed to be while(!validInput)? I meant to put that, I typed the wrong thing

Answer (score 0):

You declare variable `move` with type `int` your main method. Then your trying to launch `machineTurn` method and set its result to `move` variable. But method`s result and variable type is incompatibe -`void`can`t be presented as `int`. Compilator say so.

You should change method`s machineTurn signature to return int

```
public static int machineTurn(int theSeed)
```

Do not forget to change implementation to return int value of move you just made